# Read data from multiple text files

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have my text files in a folder. They all contains letters and numbers. For example one of my tex file contains:

```
db: localhost
data created: 2016-01-18
user: root
pass: usbw
```

So I want to scan all my files in my folder. And print info inside every text file to the screen.
So far was trying to use this code:

```
class FileHandle {
    int i;
    String a;
    String b;

    public void openFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File dir = new File("C:/Folder/DB");
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
                String f = file.getName();
                System.out.println("File name:" + f);
                while (s.hasNext()) {
                    if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                        i = s.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("int: " + i);
                    }
                    a = s.next();
                    b = s.next();
                    System.out.printf("%s", a);
                    System.out.printf("%s", b);
                    s.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got an error:

```
File name:LocalDB.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1070)
localhostCreated:   at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:1334)
    at databasesearch.FileHandle.openFile(FileHandle.java:30)
    at databasesearch.DatabaseSearch.main(DatabaseSearch.java:21)
 C:\Users\D1sturbance\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-     snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: I indented your code. Now you should see the problem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `s.close();` or move it to the outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: still the same problem :(

Comment: I think you  can clean and build your code again! :) OR restart your IDE.